# I am new in c++ .After learning basic I want to make tic tac toe.For printing board i write below code but it shows errors

Tags: c++, arrays

I am new in c++ . After learning basic I want to make tic tac toe.

For printing board I write below code but it shows errors:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char board[8]={'_','_','_\n','_','_','_\n','_','_','_\n'};
    
    cout<<'|'+ board[0]+'|'+ board[1]+'|'+ board[2]<<endl;
    cout<<'|'+ board[3]+'|'+ board[4]+'|'+ board[5]<<endl;
    cout<<'|'+ board[6]+'|'+ board[7]+'|'+ board[8]<<endl;
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `'_\n'` -- How many characters does this show?  And if you're using `cout` with `endl`, what is the reason for trying to insert newlines directly in the `board` array?

Comment: Besides what the first comment already said: `board[8]` is a `char` array of the size `8`, and how many entries does `{'_','_','_\n','_','_','_\n','_','_','_\n'}` have?

Comment: i remove \n but it still shows this:error: too many initializers for 'char [8]'

Comment: I suggest including the text of the errors, verbatim, in your question.

Comment: What it the question?

Answer (score 2):

There are several mistakes here:

1. `too many initializers for ‘char [8]’`
   You define board to contain 8 elements, and apply 9 elements in the items list.
2. `narrowing conversion of ‘24330’ from ‘int’ to ‘char’`
   `'_\n'` are 2 chars, and not a single char.

Fix:

```
char board[12] = {'_', '_', '_', '\n', '_', '_', '_', '\n', '_', '_', '_', '\n'};
```

The third mistake is an algorithmic mistake and not a compile mistake- iterate over an array elements using a [loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for).

Comment: i remove '\n'.but it is still showing same error :too many initializers for 'char [8]

Comment: @SrijalRajBhattarai `char board[8] = {'_', '_', '\n', '_', '_', '\n', '_', '_'};`  works fine to me.

Comment: but it doesnot works for me@KorelK

Comment: @SrijalRajBhattarai Please post here / update you question your new line, so I can help.

Comment: There's also the char addition in the output statements.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to not specify any array bounds when declaring an array that is being initialized:

```
char board[]={'_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_'};
```

The compiler will automatically determine the number of characters being initialized.

What if there were 67 or 142 items?  Hopefully you wouldn't be trying to count and figure out the number to place in the array, as that is error prone.  Let the compiler do this work for you.

Second, `'_\n'` is not a single character.  If you actually wanted to put new line characters in the array:

```
char board[]={'_','_','_','\n','_','_','_','\n','_','_','_','\n'};
```

If you later want to know the number of characters:

```
const int num_characters = sizeof(board) / sizeof(board[0]);
```

or if you are using C++17 or later:

```
std::size(board);
```

Comment: #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
char board[3][3]={{'1','2','3'},{'4','5','6'},{'7','8','9'}};
void display_board(){ 
    cout<<' | '<< board[0]<<' | '<< board[1]<<' | '<< board[2]<<endl;
    cout<<' | '<< board[3]<<' | '<< board[4]<<' | '<< board[5]<<endl;
    cout<<' | '<< board[6]<<' | '<< board[7]<<' | '<< board[8]<<endl;}

int main(){
    
    display_board();
    
    return 0;
} is this valid?

Comment: @SrijalRajBhattarai Maybe you should have edited the question instead of posting code as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

As previous answers have already pointed out. There two things to change:

1. Remove '\n'
2. Change the board array size.
3. Remove `+` sign because it will just add two characters as if it is two numbers.

So here's the result after those three:

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
        char board[9]={'_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_'};    
        cout << '|' << board[0] << '|' << board[1] << '|' << board[2] << endl;
        cout << '|' << board[3] << '|' << board[4] << '|' << board[5] << endl;
        cout << '|' << board[6] << '|' << board[7] << '|' << board[8] << endl;
    
        return 0;
    }
```

NB: I edited my answer and added third step after below comment.

Comment: this also does not work.it prints integer garbage value

Comment: @SrijalRajBhattarai. Thank you for your comment. The issue is the plus sign. You can use  it if you were to combine two strings but here you're combining two characters. So the results of course will be a number. I have edited my code and now I'm sure it works.